# Detect re-purchase of in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

How can I detect this situation in code:

- User purchase a full version with in-app purchase.
- User delete the application from iPhone.
- User installed the application again
- User purchases full version,

My problem is that in testing, I can see a message box saying "you already purchased...", but in the application `updateTransactions` not called.

In this situation I need to change to full version. How can I detect this event?
I.e., How can I know in my application that the user already purchased so I will "open" to full version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`. It will force your app to receive transactions again.

See docs:

- [Restoring transactions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)
- [- restoreCompletedTransactions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions)

Comment: just to make sure :
I call "restoreCompletedTransactions" and then call "addpayment" ? 

because I DO want the user to see "you already purchased" from apple, but also detect this in code to open content..

Comment: No, only restoreCompletedTransactions. Why you need to interfere a user with annoying messages?

Comment: restoreCompletedTransactions will prompt for user password.
so i think it's better to call it only when user press some button.

Comment: nothing happen..when calling "restoreCompletedTransactions" after i enter the password. not my lucky day.

Comment: The good practice is to place button, e.g., "Restore purchases" in your in-app store.